# Is there a concept of parallel universes in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture

According to what I know, Hindu texts have always focused on cyclic nature of universe. But have only mentioned this one universe only and that it will be created and get destroyed over and over again.

Is there any mention of other universes or multiverse or of the word *infinite* in terms of number of universes.

Comment: depends on what you mean by universe ? there is just one prakriti-mandalam. Within that, there are millions of andas. Each anda contains 14 lokas, with a Brahma & Shiva & svarga and naraka and bhuloka etc. You can say there are multiple worlds, but only one universe. And there is nothing like 'parallel', or 'simultaneous'. They are separated by distance and inhabited by different souls, not the same jivas living 2 separate lives simultaneously in 2 different places.

Comment: According to this it seems our universe is a lok. But then what are other 13 loks?

Comment: no.. loka = bhumi, or svarga, or naraka etc. 14 such lokas (from patala to satya loka) = 1 anda. there are koti innumerable andas. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loka